# T-SQL Substring Regex?

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, select, substring

I have a problem extracting substrings. I'm logging some SQL queries in my database and need to filter that.

Possible strings can look like these 2 examples:

```
1. [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName$TableExtra]
2. "DatabaseName".dbo."TableName$TableExtra"
```

I've tried this:

```
DECLARE @c AS NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'
"DatabaseName".dbo."TableName$TableExtra"
'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@c, PATINDEX('%"DatabaseName".dbo."%', @c) + 20, 100), 1,
                        PATINDEX('%"%', SUBSTRING(@c, PATINDEX('%"DatabaseName".dbo."%', @c) + 20, 100)) - 1)
```

That will only work with the second example but with the first one.

Can anyone help me how to write the filter that works for both samples?

Have a nice day

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: If you are trying to say that you will be processing complete queries, e.g. a common table expression with 42 joins and 13 comments, and extracting the referenced table name(s) then you need to be looking for a _TSQL parser_.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract tablenames etc, you can use [PARSENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @c AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ='"DatabaseName".dbo."TableName$TableExtra"'

SELECT PARSENAME(@c, 1) TableName
,       PARSENAME(@c, 2) SchemaName
,       PARSENAME(@c, 3) DatabaseName
```

Results in:

```
+----------------------+------------+--------------+
|      TableName       | SchemaName | DatabaseName |
+----------------------+------------+--------------+
| TableName$TableExtra | dbo        | DatabaseName |
+----------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hey HoneyBadger
Thank you but its not exactly what im looking for. 
The nvarchar normally containts different sized sql querys and i need to find the both examples to extract only the Tablename of it